Почему функция не ловит состояние в aiogram3?
В функции sendRassInLs я задаю состояние linksForRas. Почему когда пользователь заходит в состояние linksForRas и отправляет сообщение, в функции gotLinksForRass должно ловиться состояние linksForRas и отправить сообщение Сообщение получено!, но оно то ловит то нет.
Из-за чего это?
async def sendRassInLs(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Rass.linksForRas)
    await callback.message.edit_text('<b>Введите сообщение:</b>', reply_markup=kb.BackToRass, parse_mode='html')


@router.message(Rass.linksForRas)
async def gotLinksForRass(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(linksForRas=message.text)
    await message.delete()
    await message.answer("Сообщение получено!: ")
    await state.set_state(Rass.msgForRas)



@router.message(Rass.msgForRas)
async def send_msg_in_ls(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(msgForRas=message.text)
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    token = await get_token_from_database(user_id)
    data = await state.get_data()
    accsForRass = data["linksForRas"]
    msg = data["linksForRas"]
    остальной код...


Cостояние:
class Rass(StatesGroup):
    linksForRas = State()
    msgForRas = State()

И почему все время в логах мне пишет:
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher:Failed to fetch updates - TelegramConflictError: Telegram server says - Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
WARNING:aiogram.dispatcher:Sleep for 3.471689 seconds and try again... (tryings = 4, bot id = 7024637563)


У вас запущено два бота на одном токене, именно поэтому вы всегда видите такую ошибку в логах, возможно, поэтому и не ловится состояние, ведь сейчас запущен  "старый" код(где ещё нет состояний), а вы пытаетесь запустить "новый".
Telegram server says - Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

А можно как-то проверить на каких токенах сейчас  этот бот? Т.к я даже когда создаю нового бота в Bot Father соответственно получаю новый токен и использую его в боте у меня опять через время эта ошибка появляется.

@AslanPAPA возможно,  вы не закрываете старые скрипты, посмотрите в дистпетчере, сколько Python процессов запущено

На Linux в командной строке я ввел следующие команды:

Посмотрел на идентификатор процесса (PID)
ps -aux | grep <ИМЯ_СКРИПТА>

И ввел команду что бы убить этот процесс
kill -9 <PID>


